# 2 level dropdown list using CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list. However, it is not working well. At the first level, I hover my mouse to forum and it works. However, 'Digital forum' and "Politics forum' should not appear until 'Singapore forum' is hovered.

I can't seem to edit my codes to make this happen. Would really appreciate if someone can help me. Will be good if jsfiddle is used to present the answer too. Huge thanks in advance!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Standard Chartered Bank</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Twitter</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#" >Forum</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HardWare Zone</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Singapore Forum</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Digital Forum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Politics Forum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="form">
    <br>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
    <br>
    <formspace>Name:</formspace><input type="text" name="fname" class="bord"><br>
    <formspace>Age:</formspace> <input type="text" name="age" class="bord"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    #menu{
        width: 1200px;
        height: 35px;
        font-family: Arial
        font-size: 13px;
        padding:0;    
        background-color:#F23;
        text-align: center;
        z-index:1;
    }
    #menu ul{
        margin:auto;
        width:240px;
        height:35px;
        text-align:center;
        padding:0;
    }
    #menu li{
    float:left; 
    padding: 0;
    height:35px;
    width:60px;
    list-style-type: none;

    position:relative;
    }

    #menu li a{
        color:#000; 
    }
    #menu ul li ul{
        display:none;
        width:150px;
    }
    #menu ul li:hover{
        background-color:blue;  
    }
    #menu ul li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        top:14px;
        float:none;

    }
    #menu ul li ul li{
        width:140px;
        height:35px;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px;
        float:none;
    }

    #menu ul li ul li:hover ul{
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        left:145px;
        top:-25px;
        float:none;
    }

    #menu ul li ul li ul li{
        list-style-type: none;  
        width:120px;
    }
    formspace{
        width:70px;
        float:left;
    }
    input.bord{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing your javascript, or are you trying to all of this using just css?

Comment: I am just doing it with css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed these 2 css. You need to specify only immediate child ul to appear on hover. you were missing `>` selector. SO it was basically making all the ul's under it appear (including sub menu) when you hover the parent one.

[Read Child Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Child_selectors)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9VZG/)

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    top:14px;
    float:none;

}


#menu ul li ul li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    left:145px;
    top:-25px;
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: wow. thanks so much PSL! May I know what does the '>' do? How did it solve my problem?

Comment: What it does is that your style will get applied only to the immediate child ul of hovered li. Lack of that selector will select all uls under hovered li. hecne all menus were appearing.

Comment: @mrghost1988 Please mark as accepted answer, if you are satisfied with the solution and information.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ">" to this rule:

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
position:relative;
top:14px;
float:none;
}
```